# Firebase Dynamic Link Android iosParameters setFallbackUrl ('ifl') doesn't set

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have just an Android app and no iOS app. So I was trying to set a fallback url (to our web content) when any iOS user clicks on the dynamic link.

I am constructing a firebase dynamic link using the `dynamic-links-ktx` apis like this:

```
Firebase.dynamicLinks.shortLinkAsync(ShortDynamicLink.Suffix.SHORT) {

   androidParameters(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID) {
     fallbackUrl = Uri.parse(webUrl) 
   }

   iosParameters(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID) {
      setFallbackUrl(Uri.parse(webUrl)) // Show web content. <- This doesn't work
   } 
   
   link = Uri.parse(finalUrl)

   domainUriPrefix = "https://prefix-url"
  
   socialMetaTagParameters {
     ...
   }

}.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
   onSuccess(result.shortLink)
}.addOnFailureListener {
  // Log error
}
```

So, this way I create the deep link. I don't have an ios app so obviously I cannot set ios bundle name etc so I am setting just `setFallbackUrl` in `iosParameters`.
Somehow this doesn't work. On viewing the deeplink flowchart, ios doesnt resolve to the fallback url. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If so mind sharing details?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have ibi (iOS ID) set for the ifl (iOS fallback link) to work.

I think this is an oversight by the Firebase team, it makes sense to either use ofl or let us set ifl instead of the deeplink when the app doesn't exist on iOS, but it  is what it is.